# Getting this error in AWS { "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda'" } (S3+Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Hey there I just started working with AWS Lambda and S3, I got some functions from coworkers uploaded there, those works fine.

The problem was when I tried to upload my functions, I got this `{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda'"
}` as the result of why my function was not working.

I supposed that my function was not well formed but I have done some test concluding that the problem is the way I zip the project because if I download a functional project zipped and upload again it works but if I unzip it and upload it does not run.

Im working on python 2.7 and I have already tried to zip it on linux and giving it global permissions.

Comment: Hey! Can you give us a little more information about the code? Please show us the Import you're using and what you're trying to do. In your case the filesystem layout of the zip might be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zipping the file contents inside the folder instead of zipping the folder directly. For example - if your folder containing your lambda is called 'lambda_function' don't zip the folder instead go into the folder and zip the contents from there. This might be issue you're facing as I ran into an issue uploading with the same error code you mentioned when I first started using Lambda too.

Comment: Well, it perfectly worked, I could not imagine that it was the fault. Thanks!